# Clip text in excel mac 15.xx.x

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, mac, formatting

How to clip text/strings in Excel cells? The width and height of the cells should remain unchanged (so not wrap) and the text should not be displayed in the adjacent empty cell.

Excel 15.13.1
OSX 10.11

Answer (score 1):

You need to:
Select the cells you wish to clip. Open the format cells window, then, under Alignment choose the option "Fill" for Horizontal Alignment.

I found a much more complete answer than mine [here](https://superuser.com/a/990321/508402).